# Spyder randomly fails to locate chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, spyder

I am using python via spyder to do some web scraping. My code seems to be working fine, but after a few times I open and close chromedriver during the same session of spyder, when I run

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:/Python34/Scripts/chromedriver.exe')
```

I get the error message

```
WebDriverException: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be available in the path.
```

I tried downloading the latest version of chromedriver, but the issue persists. The suggestion I found [here](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/hAEhyK-63Gc) says to download the 64bit version of chromedriver, but I was not able to get a hold of that. Is this solvable anyhow? Any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

Using chromedriver, this was solved using quit() instead of close() to end each session of chrome.

Comment: In case anyone is interested I worked around this simply by using webdriver.Firefox()

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Python34/Scripts/chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: Thanks, but it keeps giving the same problem

Comment: Can you please verify the executable file name and address?

Comment: They should be correct. The point is the command usually works, but after I run it say 7 times within same session of Spyder it gives back the error message. Then I have to quit and re-start spyder, and so on